# Como quebrar uma lista e transformar em matriz no Python?

Tags: python, lista, matriz

No caso, eu quero transformar uma lista de uma coluna em uma matriz 3x3 em ordem númerica:

```
lista =([[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4],
     [5],
     [6],
     [7],
     [8],
     [9]])
```

Sendo o resultado esperado:

```
([[7 8 9]
 [4 5 6]
 [1 2 3]])
```

Comment: Verifica a função reshape, mas ela precisa de um array, mas pra converter isso ai não deve ser difícil

Answer (score 2):

Usando numpy:

```
import numpy as np
lista = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(9, 1)
print(lista)
'''
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
'''
```

Agora podemos fazer:

```
lista = lista.reshape(3, 3)[::-1] # forma-lo em 3 linhas e 3 colunas, e inverter
print(lista)
'''
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3]])
'''
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/hlkqA0)